# Start mysql without XAMPP

Tags: python, xampp

I am currently working on a program based on mysql.
Before I run my code on python though, I always have to start mysql over to XAMPP panel. Is there an option without XAMPP?

Comment: You can install MySQL separately on your windows/mac and start always with the startup .

Comment: Thanks it did it that way